# what is 'QtGui.QApplication.setGraphicsSystem("raster")'?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt4

when using pyqt, I often get a warning advising me to use the instruction `QtGui.QApplication.setGraphicsSystem("raster")`. Why and what is 'raster' ?

Also, when should I do it ? in the pyqt doc I read: 'This function is only effective before the QApplication constructor is called'. But python seems happy if I insert it like that:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
QtGui.QApplication.setGraphicsSystem("raster") # why? just to please a Warning ?
app.exec_()
```

---

additional information. The warning is:

```
Warning: QApplication was created before pyqtgraph was imported; there may be problems (to avoid bugs, call QApplication.setGraphicsSystem("raster") before the QApplication is created).
```

I use python 3.5.1 on Mac OS 10.11 with pyqt 4.11.4 and pyqtgraph 0.9.10

When I do not use `setGraphicsSystem("raster")` my GUI is sometimes not displayed, although it works most of the time. I didn’t see why/where/when it bugs or anything that could help in predicting it, there is no message, just the GUI is not displayed. So I use this instruction just pragmatically.

note: I do not particularly want to use `setGraphicsSystem("raster")`. It’s just that I am curious of what it means. Even if it seems explicit, I don't quite understand the message, maybe because I don't know what "raster" is.

Comment: read this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#setGraphicsSystem

Comment: yes, thx, I saw this, this is where I found the instruction about QApplication constructor. but it doesn't answer my questions

Comment: can you provide more information ? e.g the warning you get, the system you are using, and the python version

Comment: **Sets the default graphics backend to system, which will be used for on-screen widgets and QPixmaps. The available systems are "native", "raster" and "opengl".**

Comment: If you don't know what the method does, why are you trying to use it? What are you trying to achieve?